# Раскрутка сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, seo

Тут заказчик сказал приобрести ссылки (на его сайт, я так понял). Что это значит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Купить на других сайтах (спец.ресурсы) услугу, суть которой заключается в том, чтобы они у себя разместили ссылку на ваш сайт

Используется для продвижения сайта в поисковых системах, насколько я знаю для Яндекса уже не работает, т.к. они изменили алгоритм поднятия сайтов и если на ваш сайт ссылаются сайты с отличной тематикой, то ваш сайт уйдет в вниз

Comment: Аааа, то есть я просто должен купить права размещения контекстной рекламы на некоторых популярных сайтах или есть какие то специальные?

Comment: Ну вообще есть специальные сервисы, вы заказываете продвижение сайта, они за вас размещают рекламу(ссылки на ваш сайт) на сайтах той тематики, которую вы выберете

Comment: Скинь пожалуйста ссылку, такого сервиса. Спасибо =)

Answer (score 4):

Согласно **[справки Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=ru)**: "*Ссылки, предназначенные для изменения показателя PageRank или позиции сайта в результатах поиска Google, могут считаться частью схемы обмена ссылками и нарушением рекомендаций Google для веб-мастеров. К ним могут относиться как входящие, так и исходящие ссылки.... Покупка или продажа ссылок...*". Объясните вашему заказчику, что его сайт, в результате этих манипуляций, имеет рсик получить санкции Гугл.